# Google Plus One button shows fine on blog post but not on blog home page?

Tags: google-plus-one

I have a site where we're loading a Google +1 button at the end of each blog post. On the home page, where it shows the teaser of the blog post it shows the same +1 button but it doesn't correspond with the amount of times it's been +1'd.

Not sure where to start on de-bugging this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by checking if the url parameter for the button has been set. If that's not been set, the button usually look for the rel canonical tag or finally for the location from DOM.

From [Google Plus API](http://code.google.com/apis/+1button/#target-url)